# My class cant be found or load

Tags: java, class, find, package, load

I just made two classes with one package, but when I run program it says 'Could not find or load main class', but when I remove package p; from main program everything is right.package p;
package p;

```
public class Ex5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```

Whats wrong with that package?

```
package p;

public class Help {
    int x;
    int y;

    public void Help(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;  
    }   

}
```

Comment: why are you creating a package with main method the purpose of package is to be imported to main method and does not contain the main method itself

Comment: I tried also import p.*; and it says package p doesnt exist

Comment: you must not include the main method itself in a package just some classes

Comment: Hopefully this will help you.
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 0):

in creating a package you must follow the java naming convention

to create a package you must name it using the company website in reverse order

e.g. if your company is `dawidyenko.com` you should create a `package com.dawidyenko;`

after creating a package you can then import it in your main method using

`import com.dawidyenko.Help;`

note that  your package is not like java built in packages so you must include the class name and must not use the `*` wild card symbol

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. You can get everything from the Help class.

```
import p.Help;
public class Ex5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```